# Jstl tag link . Manual upload of tld or taglib

Tags: jstl, jsp-tags

[image]

every time i try linking it give me error . plus addition to this i even tried to get the tld file but every time i get is jar for that . I just want to use the jstl tags like `<c:out>` and such.

Comment: Do you have `jstl.jar` included in your classpath? Additionally, the URI should be `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core` (unless you're on an on extremely old version, in which case you should update anyways).

Comment: we are using eclipse luna

Comment: Excellent, I've added the comment as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `jstl.jar` included in your classpath.

Additionally, the URI should be `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core` (unless you're on an on extremely old version, in which case you should update anyways).

See our [JSTL info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) for more detailed information, including where to download the jar.